# Element with same height and width in px renders as non-square

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a simple three vertical dot menu, and I'm encountering some rather strange behavior. Even though they all have a determined height and width, the three dots render as non-square, seemingly depending on the grandparent container's dimensions. I've tried using `px`, `rem`, `em`, and percentages to size them, but the issue persists.

I've also tried laying the dots out by setting the parent element's width and height explicitly and making it flexbox, as well as removing all the padding and margin both on the parent and dots, but nothing seems to alleviate the issue. The code looks like this:

```css
.grandparent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}

.item1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.item1 img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
}

.item2 {
  flex: 1 1;
}

.title {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 0 5px 13px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.subtitle {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 13px;
  margin-top: -9px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #808080;
}

.parent {
  margin-right: 11px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dot {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #808080;
}

.no-appearance {
  appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent" style="width: 375px; height: 50px">
  <div class="item1"><a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" /></a></div>
  <div class="item2">
    <div class="title">Example text</div>
    <div class="subtitle">Example text</div>
  </div>
  <button class="parent no-appearance">
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </button>
</div>
```

Edit: I added some more code to the snippet to try to reproduce the issue, but unfortunately it does not seem to be reproducible even though it is consistently reproducible in my development environment.

Here's an example of how this renders in Chrome 88.0 when the grandparent is 410x50:

[image: decent dots]

... and here's what it looks like when the grandparent is 375 x 50:

[image: distorted dots]

Any idea what might be at play here?

Comment: maybe in your dev.environment is more CSS that somehow give `.parent` or `.dot` a little pading or `min-with`? Try selecting one of the dots in your chrome dev-tools and look for 
inherited styles

Comment: @Atomkind I've checked using Chrome Dev Tools and I couldn't find any size-related inherited properties. According to Dev Tools, the size is perfectly square.

Comment: is there a space in the div? a nonbreakspace, normal space (or line-break) or `&nbsp;`?

Comment: @Atomkind No, they're all identical and all closed immediately. I've also tried setting `overflow: hidden` to rule out something like that.

Answer (score 0):

What about html-entitie `&vellip;`?

https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_v.asp

```css
.target {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.target::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #808080;
  content: '\0022EE';
}
.target:hover::after{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="target"></div>
```

Comment: I considered creating an SVG for it or using an icon font, but this is a nice pure HTML workaround. I didn't know there was a HTML entity for this, so thanks for the tip. Might just go with this since I can't seem to reproduce the issue in the code snippet.

Comment: There is a realy big list of possible symbols and also emojis. But look in your environment for styles for `div` or `button` or `.dot` or `.parent` or `.no-appearance`